# "Failed to load swt-pi3" error in e2studio installer

Tags: fedora, java, eclipse

I would like to install the latest version of Renesas' e2studio on my up-to-date Fedora 39 machine but I keep getting the following error:

```
$ ./e2studio_installer-2024-01_1_linux_host.run 
Mar. 31, 2024 3:19:36 P.M. org.apache.aries.spifly.BaseActivator log
INFO: Registered provider org.slf4j.simple.SimpleServiceProvider of service org.slf4j.spi.SLF4JServiceProvider in bundle slf4j.simple
SWT OS.java Error: Failed to load swt-pi3, loading swt-pi4 as fallback.
```

I've installed the `eclipse-swt` package and confimed that I have Java installed:

```
$ java --version
openjdk 17.0.9 2023-10-17
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (Red_Hat-17.0.9.0.9-4) (build 17.0.9+9)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (Red_Hat-17.0.9.0.9-4) (build 17.0.9+9, mixed mode, sharing)
```

I have tried to find a solution by searching the web but have not succeeded so far. Can anyone here help me to get this resolved?